# Check if python dictionary contains value and if so return related value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dicts, which contain filenames and modification dates in the following format:

```
fileList = [{"fileName": "file1.txt", "fileMod": "0000048723"}, 
            {"fileName": "file2.txt", "fileMod": "0000098573"}]
```

I need to query if a `fileName` exists in the dictionary and if so return the fileMod value for that entry.

Comment: Is that dictionary an example of an entry into another dictionary/list/something else or what? How does the filemode relate to the filename? Etc... Would be nice to have it a bit more clear :)

Comment: How fileMod is related to fileName? Could you present an example with at least two filenames and two filemods?

Comment: Sorry, I realise lookng back that its not so clear. I have updated the  question to show the data structure more completely

Comment: _"I have a dictionary"_ -- no, you have a list of dictionaries.

Comment: If your only concerns are the file name and the file mode, and each file name can appear at most once, then it would be even better to have a dictionary like this: `fileList = {"file1.txt": "0000048723", "file2.txt": "0000098573"}`. If you need more properties per file, then you can still make the filename the key for the dictionary, and use something else (eg. a list or another dictionary) as the values. Then you can do something like: `fileList.get(filename, <defaultvaluereturnedifthekeyisnotthere>)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a list comprehension:

```
fileMod = [item['fileMod'] for item in fileList if item['fileName'] == filename]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [lambda](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms) with [filter](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter).

```
>>> fileList = [{"fileName": "filename1.typ", "fileMod": "0000000001"}, {"fileName": "filename2.typ", "fileMod": "0000000002"}]
>>> filter(lambda x:x["fileName"]=="filename2.typ",fileList)[0]['fileMod']
'0000000002'
```

You can also do this using [List-Comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
[x['fileMod'] for x in fileList if x["fileName"]=="filename2.typ"][0]
```

Or Just a simple Iteration

```
for x in fileList:
    if x["fileName"]=="filename2.typ":
        print x["fileMod"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record: your data structure is a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary. So you cannot simply query the list for the item `"fileName"`. You could do it like this:

```
for filedict in fileList:
    if filedict.get("fileName") == "myrequestedfile.typ":
        # to somthing
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Right, you've updated your question to indicate a list of dicts as Janne pointed out. But now your statement is not true that:

> I am checking if the fileName exists using if filename in filelist: statement, which is working correctly

Ricardo got it right,  you need a dict of modTimes or a dict of dicts.  Easily created from your fileList with:

```python
fileList = dict((f['fileName'],f) for f in fileList) 
mod = fileList.get('file1.txt',<default>)
# or
fileList = dict((f['fileName'],f) for f in fileList)
mod = fileList.get('file1.txt',{}).get('fileMod',<default>)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem nicely using a [`generator`](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-generator) and the [`next`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.next) method:

```
next(x['fileMod'] for x in fileList if x['fileName'] == 'my filename')
```

Of course, this raises a `StopIteration` error if the generator is empty (there was no dict with `fileName == 'my filename'` in your list). You can avoid the error raised with:

```
try:
    next(x['fileMod'] for x in fileList if x['fileName']=='my filename')
except StopIteration:
    print 'Oops! file not found'
```