# checkin python if a list of dictonaries does NOT contain a specific value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This is some what of a supplementary question to my recent query about searching dictionary items in a list:

[Check if python dictionary contains value and if so return related value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695177/check-if-python-dictionary-contains-value-and-if-so-return-related-value)

I have an array containing dictionaries in the format:

```
fileList = [
               {"fileName": "file1.txt", "fileMod": "0000048723"}, 
               {"fileName": "file2.txt", "fileMod": "0000098573"}
           ]
```

I was able to return a list of fileMod values for existing items in the fileList using 
a rather neat list comprehension as suggested:

```
fileMod = [item['fileMod'] for item in fileList if item['fileName'] == filename]
```

This returns a value if there is a matching filename, but I forgot to include that I also need to know when there is a filename that does not match any of the entries in filelist.

I am sure this should be simple, but I think I have just been looking at it too long to see the woods for the trees.

Comment: You want to do this for a specific filename or for all of them?

Comment: Just check if the `fileMod` list is empty?

Comment: I put a comment to your previous question with the same suggestion as @PaulHankin's answer to this one. You should use a dictionary with filename as the key, not a list of dictionaries, unless there are repeated filenames. In that case, you can just `filename in files` **but als** `filename not in files`, which solves both your problems

Comment: Responses are coming thick and fast, I am not sure who to answer first.  I have tried using an if statement to check if len(fileMod) > 0 but the when the fileMod list IS empty the else statement never fires.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you should use a dictionary rather than a list?

```
files = {
    'file1.txt': {'fileMod': '0000048723'},
    'file2.txt': {'fileMod': '0000048723'}
}
```

This stores the same information as your list, but finding elements is easy:

```
mod = None
if 'file1.txt' in files:
    mod = files['file1.txt']['fileMod']
```

Comment: I would stress that finding elements with your dictionary is **faster**. And Finglish should probably rethink his way to use lists and dictionaries...

Comment: In the end I decided you were right and I simplified everything by using a dictionary rather than a list.

Answer (score 2):

**"checkin python if a list of dictonaries does NOT contain a specific value"**

```
if not any(item for item in fileList if item['fileName'] == filename):
```

returns true if no dictionary in your list fulfills the condition.

This is possibly faster than checking the whole `fileMod`, because it stops as soon as a match is found.

---

**"This returns a value if there is a matching filename, but I forgot to include that I also need to know when there is a filename that does not match any of the entries in filelist."** (a different question?)

```
fileMod = []
fileBad = []
for item in fileList:
    if item['fileName'] == filename:
        fileMod.append(item['fileMod'])
    else:
        fileBad.append(item['fileMod'])
```

or

```
fileMod = {True: [], False: []} # a dictionary of lists
for item in fileList:
    fileMod[item['fileMod'] == filename].append(item['fileMod'])
```

This last code returns a dict of lists: `fileMod[True]` is a list of positive founds, `fileMod[False]` is a list of negative founds.

Answer (score 2):

If the filename doesn't match any entry in the filelist then the list fileMod would be empty.

```
>>> if fileMod:
...     # Code when the filename matches at least one file
... else:
...     # Code when the filename doesn't match any entry.
```

To check for empty lists in python:

```
>>> l = []
>>> if l:
...     print "not empty"
... else:
...     print "empty"
... 
empty
```

Comment: I tried this but for some reason when the fileMod length is 0 the else  never fires

Comment: You don't need to check for length. I am adding sample code to show that.

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that

```
fileMod = [item['fileMod'] for item in fileList if item['fileName'] == filename]
```

returns a **list** of modifications dates (not a value), 
if the list has zero length then there are no items in fileList matching the filename.

Comment: Ok, I get you.  The only problem is that if I print len(fileMod) after each call it only outputs the fileMod length if fileMod contains values, and for some reason does not ever return 0

Comment: Try this: 
fileMod = [item['fileMod'] for item in fileList if item['fileName'] == "file3.txt"]
if len(fileMod):
    print fileMod 
else:
    print "NoFile"